# How can I compare a string to char[] with no memory allocations?

Tags: c#, .net

In this example, I have to convert the array to a string to use the built in [String.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare.aspx) method.

```
char[] array = {'a','b','c'};
string s = "abc";

// here is the extra string allocation
var arrayString = new String(array);

var compareResult = String.Compare(s, arrayString);
```

**Is there an easy way to compare a string to a char array without an extra string allocation?**

Note: I need the compare semantics here where I need 
"[a] 32-bit signed integer that indicates the lexical relationship between the two comparands."

Less than zero -> strA is less than strB.

Zero ->  strA equals strB.

Greater than zero -> strA is greater than strB.

(I'm doing this comparision in loop and I'm generating a lot of extra garbage with the extra string allocation (25-100MB based on the size of my input)_.

I think I will probably end up getting my hands dirty and just writing the code myself.

Comment: You _can_ loop over the string - it implements `IEnumerable<Char>`.

Comment: Can you post your comparison code ? I can't understand why you generate more variables in the comparison loop ??? Just use a for each loop over the char array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
int len = Math.Min(array.Length, s.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (s[i] < array[i]) return -1;
    if (s[i] > array[i]) return +1;
}
return s.Length.Compare(array.Length);
```

Comment: But you allocate space for `len`, and `i`! (Joke, +1)

Answer (score 3):

Strings implement `IEnumerable<Char>`, so you *can* loop over them:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
   // Do comparisons of  s.Chars[i] with array[i] as wanted
}
```

The above will avoid extra string allocations (and assumes that the string length will be the same or larger than the character array length).

Comment: `IEnumerable<char>` relates to foreach/enumerator access only; the example is using *indexer* access, not enumerator. As a side effect, that does negate @Richard's observation. But it means that the first line of the answer is unrelated to the example.

Answer (score 1):

How about using SequentialEqual?

```
char[] array = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
string s = "abc";
bool result = array.SequentialEqual(s);
```

Result is true if they are equal and false if they are different.

I know it does not Compare a the array and the string, it only checks if they are equal.  Others have made a better answer to this question.

Okay, here comes my solution based on the solution from @FlyingStreudel and @Olivier Jacot-Descombes:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char[] array = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
    string s = "abc";
    s.Compare(array);
}
```

...

```
public static class StringUtils
{
    public static int Compare(this String str, char[] chars)
    {
        if (str == null && chars == null) return 0;
        if (str == null) return -1;
        if (chars == null) return 1;
        int max = Math.Min(str.Length, chars.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            if (str[i] < chars[i])
                return -1;
            else if (str[i] > chars[i])
                return 1;
        return str.Length.CompareTo(chars.Length);
    }
}
```

The main difference is that I do not compare i with chars.Length for every char.

Hope this will help you in your quest.

Comment: This will just give you whether these are equal or not - not if one is _larger_ than the other, as the OP specified.

Comment: And it will allocate memory for the enumerators.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The idea is just to avoid copying the whole array into a new string just to be able to compare, not to program without ever using any memory at all.  He's looking for an O(1) memory footprint rather than O(n).

Comment: @Servy: Another point is whether you are allocating memory on the stack or on the heap. Creating millions of objects on the heap generates a lot of work for the GC.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The point is this won't allocate anything based on the size of the array.  There is just one enumerator per sequence, rather than something allocated per character.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, you are right. This could be important, especially if long strings have to be compared.

Comment: This appears to only be missing null checks for the parameters.

Comment: @cfeduke: just added null checking.

Comment: `ArgumentNullException` is okay, but string comparisons to null should be a defined state: `not null` > `null`, and typically when `null` == `null` is 0 (even though `null` is never truly equivalent I often see exceptions made when comparing, specifically for sorting).

Comment: @cfeduke: I have changed the null handling - your suggestions seems reasonable and fairly easy to implement.  Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an extension method:

```
public static int Compare(this String str, char[] chars)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        if (i == chars.Length)
            return 1;
        else if (str[i] < chars[i])
            return -1;
        else if (str[i] > chars[i])
            return 1;
    if (chars.Length > str.Length)
        return -1;           
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wrong! If `str = "abc"` and `chars = { 'z' }` then `chars > str`. The OP wants a lexical order.

Comment: Doh, didn't realize that was how lexical order worked! I will resolve this post-haste!